# File manager with better performance over CIFS than Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, samba, cifs

I want to manage media files on Ubuntu, but since the server has a lot of files and folders, it takes ages over CIFS to update the directory changes. This is clearly a Nautilus issue - Windows 10 is much faster and also **caches results**. I can enter a subdirectory and go back without delay, not so on Ubuntu.

Is there a suitable replacement for Nautilus with better performance?

Comment: Do you mount the Samba share, or are you just accessing it over Nautilus. From my experience mounting the share will improve performance significantly.

Comment: Accessing it via Nautilus, which mounts it at `/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/<sharename>`. But I know that this mount point is special (not even root can access it, only the user), so performance impact could be an issue there.

Comment: If it is practicable for your purposes, I would mount the filesystem with mount -t cifs -o uid=yourusername,gid=users //pathtoshare /pathtomountpoint. You can put this in a script, the performance difference between this and using gvfs should be noticable.

Comment: Will give it a try and report back.

Comment: @bruni: Took some years, but I want to give you the numbers: gvfs takes 13 seconds, cifs mount takes 2 seconds for one server. Unfortunately, using static cifs mounts is too unflexible for browsing several servers.

Answer (score 1):

While the cifs mounts are working and cutting down time from 13 s to 2 s in `Nautilus` in one example, it's not the flexibility you need if you want to browse several servers.

Lately, I work with Lubuntu-next (LXQt) a lot - `PCManFM-Qt` is caching the results, unlike `Nautilus`.

So, the long wait times with gvfs only occur once, and if changes are made, again after you refresh with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

In the example above, `Nautilus` would make you wait 13 s every time you re-enter the directory, while `PCManFM-Qt` lets you jump to another directory and back without waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but as @Bruni suggested in the comments mounting over CIFS MAY help (YMMV).

For me it doesn't help BUT if I copy the files through the `cp` command through the terminal it works. Once it's mounted via CIFS I'm able to saturate my link from 600Mbps to the maximum 1 Gbps on my network. I hate having to break my workflow from nautilus to terminal but I haven't found a better solution... yet :(

I have this in my fstab:

`//192.168.x.x/myfiles /mnt/myfiles cifs credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.11,rw 0 0`

Refer to $ `man mount.cifs` on how to create a credential file.